# Angular 2 sorting with lodash

Tags: angular, sorting, lodash

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ore-table',
  templateUrl: './ore-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ore-table.component.less']
})
export class OreTableComponent implements OnInit {
  ores = '../assets/json/ores.json';
  prices = 'https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/markets/prices/?datasource=tranquility';

  oreArray: any;
  pricesArray: any;
  joinedArray: Array<any> = [];
  completeArray: Array<any> = [];

  seconds: number;
  turrets: any;
  turretYield: any;
  duration: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.seconds = 3600;
    this.turrets = 2;
    this.turretYield = 1593;
    this.duration = 106.9;
  }

  getOres() {
    this.http.get(this.ores).subscribe(data => {
      this.oreArray = data;
      this.getPrices();
    });
  }

  getPrices() {
    this.http.get(this.prices).subscribe(data => {
      this.pricesArray = data;
      this.joinPrices();
    });
  }

  joinPrices() {
    const cycles = this.seconds / this.duration;
    const totalYield = this.turretYield * this.turrets;

    this.oreArray.forEach((data) => {
      const matchingPrice = this.getMatchingPrice(data);

      const oreMined = totalYield * (1 / data.volume) * cycles;
      const hourIncome = matchingPrice.average_price.toFixed(2) * oreMined;
      const hourIncomeFormat = Number(hourIncome).toFixed();
      const isk = String(hourIncomeFormat).replace(/(.)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');

      if (matchingPrice !== false) {
          this.joinedArray.push({
              id: data.id,
              name: data.name,
              type: data.type,
              volume: data.volume.toFixed(2),
              average_price: matchingPrice.average_price.toFixed(2),
              max_income: isk,
              image: data.image
          });
      }
    });
    console.log(this.joinedArray);
    this.completeArray = _.sortBy(this.joinedArray, ['max_income']).reverse();
  }

  updatePrices(newTurrets, newTurretYield, newDuration) {
    console.log(newTurrets);
    this.joinedArray = [];

    const cycles = this.seconds / newDuration;
    const totalYield = newTurretYield * newTurrets;

    this.oreArray.forEach((data) => {
      const matchingPrice = this.getMatchingPrice(data);

      const oreMined = totalYield * (1 / data.volume) * cycles;
      const hourIncome = matchingPrice.average_price.toFixed(2) * oreMined;
      const hourIncomeFormat = Number(hourIncome).toFixed();
      const isk = String(hourIncomeFormat).replace(/(.)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');

      if (matchingPrice !== false) {
          this.joinedArray.push({
              id: data.id,
              name: data.name,
              type: data.type,
              volume: data.volume.toFixed(2),
              average_price: matchingPrice.average_price.toFixed(2),
              max_income: isk,
              image: data.image
          });
      }
    });
  }

  getMatchingPrice(data) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.pricesArray.length; i++) {
      if (this.pricesArray[i].type_id === data.id) {
            return this.pricesArray[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getOres();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let ore of completeArray" id="{{ ore.id }}">
        <td><img src="{{ ore.image }}" alt="{{ ore.name}}" /></td>
        <td><strong>{{ ore.name }}</strong></td>
        <td class="right aligned">{{ ore.volume }} m&#179;</td>
        <td class="right aligned">{{ ore.average_price }} ISK</td>
        <td class="right aligned">{{ ore.max_income }}</td>
      </tr>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I'm using lodash to sort my array by the `'max_income'` field and then applying `.reverse()` to sort it in descending order:

```
this.completeArray = _.sortBy(this.joinedArray, ['max_income']).reverse();
```

As seen in the screenshot above, it works perfectly other than the first row.  Because it starts with an 8, it's appearing first and this is completely wrong.  What adjustment can I make to force the numbers to sort properly?  Here as what an object looks like:

```
{
    "id": 17870,
    "name": "Vitreous Mercoxit",
    "type": "Mercoxit",
    "volume": "40.00",
    "average_price": "19000.04",
    "max_income": "50,964,186",
    "image": "../assets/images/Mercoxit.png"
  }
```

Comment: isk is a string, try with a number instead.

Comment: You should use number instead of string in your json for volume, average_price and max_income.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is it is compared as a string.

Try this:

```
    this.completeArray = _.sortBy(this.joinedArray,
                  (item) => {
                     return +item.max_income; 
                  }).reverse();
```

or:

```
this.completeArray = _.sortBy(this.joinedArray,
                      (item) => {
                         return +(item.max_income.replace(',', '')); 
                      }).reverse();
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure what this is doing.  The order is now non-sensical:

16,189,410 - 50,964,186 - 14,863,986 - 15,117,555...

Comment: @JoeBerthelot The code I wrote returns max_income as a number, but the problem is that it does not treat commas in the string right. You can try to replace the commas with '', and then check it.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any method which support multiple column to sort in loadash?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use `loadash` here. It's better to write your own comparison function and use the native [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.

```js
var numberCompare = (a, b) => a - b;

var arr = ['1', '20', '31', '400,000', '5', '600', '70'];
var res = arr.map(x => +x.replace(',', '')).sort(numberCompare);

console.log(res);
```

If you want a reverse sort, do `b - a` in the above function.

Answer (score 2):

The `max_income` is a string that can contain comma separators. Change the function that is passed to `sortBy` to convert the string to a number:

```
_.sortBy(this.joinedArray, item => +item.max_income.replace(',', ''))
```