# Angular 5: How do I sort Observable alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a problem I can't figure out: I want to sort data in an Observable (I assume it is at least) alphabetically.

What the code basically does is get the data from Firestore and display the startHour and startMinute variables it gets from the database inside an event title bar. That works fine. However, it does not sort the 'titles' properly. Rather than sort them alphabetically (as in, earlier times first i.e. 07:20 in front of 10:50, then 13:05) it sorts it based on the document ids shown in the database. So basically it can become 07:20, then 13:05, then 10:50, which is not what I want.

calendar.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { startOfDay, isSameDay, isSameMonth } from 'date-fns';

import { CalendarEvent, CalendarEventAction, CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent, CalendarMonthViewDay } from 'angular-calendar';

import { FuseConfirmDialogComponent } from '@fuse/components/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component';
import { fuseAnimations } from '@fuse/animations';

import { FuseCalendarEventFormDialogComponent } from './event-form/event-form.component';
import { CalendarEventModel } from './event.model';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export interface Ride { allDay: boolean; color: Object; /*primary: string; secondary: string;*/ end: Date; meta: Object; location: string; notes: string; start: Date; title: string; draggable: boolean; }
export interface RideId extends Ride { id: string }

@Component({
    selector     : 'fuse-calendar',
    templateUrl  : './calendar.component.html',
    styleUrls    : ['./calendar.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    animations   : fuseAnimations
})
export class FuseCalendarComponent implements OnInit
{   
    view: string;
    viewDate: Date;
    events: CalendarEvent[];
    locale: string = 'nl';
    public actions: CalendarEventAction[];
    activeDayIsOpen: boolean;
    refresh: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    dialogRef: any;
    confirmDialogRef: MatDialogRef<FuseConfirmDialogComponent>;
    selectedDay: any;
    rides: Observable<RideId[]>;
    ride: Observable<Ride>;

    private ridesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Ride>;
    private ridesDocument: AngularFirestoreDocument<Ride>;



    vehicles = [
        {value: 'vehicle-0', viewValue: 'Alle'},
        {value: 'vehicle-1', viewValue: 'Buurtmobiel Beuningen/Weurt'},
        {value: 'vehicle-2', viewValue: 'Buurtmobiel Ewijk/Winssen'}
    ];

    constructor(
        public dialog: MatDialog,
        private readonly db: AngularFirestore,
    )
    {
        this.view = 'month';
        this.viewDate = new Date();
        this.activeDayIsOpen = true;
        this.selectedDay = {date: startOfDay(new Date())};



        this.actions = [
            {
                label  : '<i class="material-icons s-16">edit</i>',
                onClick: ({event}: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
                    this.editEvent('edit', event);
                }
            },
            {
                label  : '<i class="material-icons s-16">delete</i>',
                onClick: ({event}: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
                    this.deleteEvent(event);
                }
            }
        ];

        /**
         * Get events from service/server
         */
         this.ridesCollection = db.collection<Ride>('rides');

         this.rides = this.ridesCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
            return actions.map(a => {
            let data = a.payload.doc.data() as Ride;
                data.draggable = true;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
      });       
    });

//        this.setEvents();
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        /**
         * Watch re-render-refresh for updating db
         */
//        this.refresh.subscribe(updateDB => {
//            // console.warn('REFRESH');
//            if ( updateDB )
//            {
//                // console.warn('UPDATE DB');
//                this.calendarService.updateEvents(this.events);
//            }
//        });

//        this.calendarService.onEventsUpdated.subscribe(events => {
//            this.setEvents();
//            this.refresh.next();
//        });

//        this.ridesDocument = this.db.doc('rides/id');
//        this.ride = this.ridesDocument.valueChanges();
    }

    /**
     * Before View Renderer
     * @param {any} header
     * @param {any} body
     */
    beforeMonthViewRender({header, body})
    {
        // console.info('beforeMonthViewRender');
        /**
         * Get the selected day
         */
        const _selectedDay = body.find((_day) => {
            return _day.date.getTime() === this.selectedDay.date.getTime();
        });

        if ( _selectedDay )
        {
            /**
             * Set selectedday style
             * @type {string}
             */
            _selectedDay.cssClass = 'mat-elevation-z3';
        }

    }

    /**
     * Day clicked
     * @param {MonthViewDay} day
     */
    dayClicked(day: CalendarMonthViewDay): void
    {
        const date: Date = day.date;
        const events: CalendarEvent[] = day.events;

        if ( isSameMonth(date, this.viewDate) )
        {
            if ( (isSameDay(this.viewDate, date) && this.activeDayIsOpen === true) || events.length === 0 )
            {
                this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Titlebar(s) that appear(s) when a day has been selected

                this.activeDayIsOpen = true;
                this.viewDate = date;
            }
        }
        this.selectedDay = day;
        this.refresh.next();
    }

    /**
     * Event times changed
     * Event dropped or resized
     * @param {CalendarEvent} event
     * @param {Date} newStart
     * @param {Date} newEnd
     */
    eventTimesChanged({event, newStart, newEnd}: CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent): void
    {
        event.start = newStart;
        event.end = newEnd;

//        console.warn('Dropped or resized', event);

        this.ridesDocument = this.db.doc('rides/' + event.id);
        console.log(event.start);
        console.log(newStart);
        this.ridesDocument.update(event);
        this.refresh.next(true);
    }

    /**
     * Delete Event
     * @param event
     */
    deleteEvent(ride)
    {
        this.confirmDialogRef = this.dialog.open(FuseConfirmDialogComponent, {
            disableClose: false
        });

        this.confirmDialogRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage = 'Are you sure you want to delete?';

        this.confirmDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            if ( result )
            {
//                const eventIndex = this.events.indexOf(event);
//                this.events.splice(eventIndex, 1);
//                this.refresh.next(true);

            }
            this.confirmDialogRef = null;
        });

    }

    /**
     * Edit Event
     * @param {string} action
     * @param {CalendarEvent} event
     */
    editEvent(action: string, event: CalendarEvent)
    {
//        const eventIndex = this.events.indexOf(event);

        this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FuseCalendarEventFormDialogComponent, {
            panelClass: 'event-form-dialog',
            data      : {
                event : event,
                action: action
            }
        });

        this.dialogRef.afterClosed()
            .subscribe(response => {
                if ( !response )
                {
                    return;
                }
                const actionType: string = response[0];
                const formData: FormGroup = response[1];
                switch ( actionType )
                {
                    /**
                     * Save
                     */
                    case 'save':
                        let saveData: any;
//                        this.events[eventIndex] = Object.assign(this.events[eventIndex], formData.getRawValue());
                        this.refresh.next(true);

                        saveData = formData.getRawValue();
//                        saveData.start.setHours(saveData.startHour);
//                        saveData.start.setMinutes(saveData.startMinute);

                        this.ridesDocument = this.db.doc('rides/' + event.id);
                        saveData.start.setHours(saveData.startHour, saveData.startMinute);
                        saveData.end.setHours(saveData.endHour, saveData.endMinute);
                        this.ridesDocument.update(saveData);

                        break;
                    /**
                     * Delete
                     */
                    case 'delete':

//                        this.deleteEvent(event);
                        this.ridesDocument = this.db.doc('rides/' + event.id);
                        this.ridesDocument.delete();

                        break;
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Add Event
     */
    addEvent(): void
    {
        this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FuseCalendarEventFormDialogComponent, {
            panelClass: 'event-form-dialog',
            data      : {
                action: 'new',
                date  : this.selectedDay.date
            }
        });
        this.dialogRef.afterClosed()
            .subscribe((response: FormGroup) => {
                if ( !response )
                {
                    return;
                }
                const newEvent = response.getRawValue();
//                newEvent.actions = this.actions;
//                this.events.push(newEvent);
                this.refresh.next(true);
                newEvent.start.setHours(newEvent.startHour, newEvent.startMinute);
                newEvent.end.setHours(newEvent.endHour, newEvent.endMinute);
                this.ridesCollection.add(newEvent);
            });
    }
}
```

I've tried using a pipe, as well as .sort() and orderBy, but it likes nothing. Perhaps I've done it in a wrong way, I cannot say, so I would love some help with this problem.

I use Fuse2 with Angular 5. The database is Angularfire2 Firestore.

Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT: I am not sure if this helps in any way, but I am able to put .sort() in here:

```
this.rides = this.ridesCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
            return actions.map(a => {
            let data = a.payload.doc.data() as Ride;
                data.draggable = true;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
      }).sort(); // Can add .sort() here without an error, but nothing happens
    });
```

But as comment says, it does nothing and whenever I try to put an argument between the () I get an error message...

Comment: Try to sorting using loadash.
Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813478/angular-2-sorting-with-lodash

Comment: @Krunal If lodash can sort it, then vanillaJS can do it too. He said he tried, the issue isn't coming from what to use to sort, but how to sort.

Comment: trichetriche@ He is using pipe so I suggest lodash and also provide link for example so may be problem will be solved.

Comment: I tried using a pipe once to order stuff, but that also didn't work. I must really be something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has a built-in function to sort by the criteria and direction you desire.

For the firestore, you can **[look here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)** , for the realtime DB, you can **[look here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)**

Comment: Thanks, but I already looked there and for some reason it didn't work. Perhaps I did something wrong, but I can't figure it out. I lack the knowledge for this since I'm just a beginner.

Comment: `db.collection<Ride>('rides').orderBy('titles', 'asc')`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I tried as well, but I get this error message every single time, no matter what I try: TS2339: Property 'orderBy' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollection<Ride> or something similar with .sort()

Comment: Again, read the documentation, you need to use this property on references of your documents. It's all explained, even in the firebase library that you're using : https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md

Comment: `db.collection<Ride>('rides', ref => ref.orderBy('titles', 'asc'))`

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem enough to most likely figure the rest out as well. I notice I still have a long way to go to learn Javascript syntax, as well as certain keywords like ref and such.

Comment: Don't make mistakes here : ref is the name of a variable, not a keyword. Here, you're simply implementing a callback function, that is a paramterer of another function. That's very basic actually. But I agree with you, if you have issues with the Javascript syntax, you should learn it before coding with it. Otherwise, you will have a really, really hard time with your code. My advice : learn EcmaScript 7, then Typescript, then Angular.

Comment: I see. Thank you :) I will keep this in mind. Thank you for all your effort and time. I appreciate it!

Comment: Also to note, firestore does not offer case insensitive sorting, so it's possible you will have to do a second sort on our own anyway after the database fetch. See: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/310